# Klingt das gut? Darf ich "seit Kurzem" in diesem Kontext verwenden?

Tags: word-usage

Mit der Studienberatung der Universität bin ich seit Kurzem ins Gespräch gekommen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Es ist zwar korrekt, klingt aber nicht zu 100% gut. "seit" drückt eher einen Zeitraum aus als einen konkreten Zeitpunkt.

Wenn Du sagen willst, dass Du noch immer in einem aktiven Gespräch / Austausch bist, dann würdest Du schreiben:

> Mit der Studienberatung der Universität bin ich seit Kurzem **im** Gespräch

Wenn Du aber sagen willst, dass Du kürzlich in Gespräch gekommen bist, dieses aber schon wieder beendet ist, dann wäre "vor" korrekt:

> Mit der Studienberatung der Universität bin ich **vor** Kurzem ins Gespräch gekommen

Wobei auch im zweiten Fall die Möglichkeit besteht, dass das Gespräch noch anhält. Hier ist eben die Betonung auf den Zeitpunkt, zu dem Du ins Gespräch gekommen bist, im Gegensatz zum Zeitraum, den das Gespräch einnimmt im ersten Beispiel.

Comment: Ich hätte noch ein gewisses Problem damit, ob man gut sagen kann, dass man mit einer Institution oder einer Abteilung oder einer Anlaufstelle, mit der Servicestelle einer Einrichtung o.Ä. 'ins Gespräch kommen' kann. Ich würde diese Formulierung immer auf eine Einzelperson beziehen, bei der Instanz innerhalb eine institutionellen Struktur würde ich eher sagen 'in Kontakt / im Austausch stehen mit', oder wenn es darum geht, den Beginn dieses Kontakts zu markieren, 'seit ... gibt es eine Diskussion zwischen ...'. Wie gesagt, 'ins Gespräch kommen' würde ich mit einem Mitarbeiter der Einrichtung.

Comment: Man kann statt *Gespräch* auch einfach *Kontakt* verwenden, dann sind auch e-Mails, Briefe, und Faxe mit abgedeckt und die Formulierung ist weniger empfindlich in der Hinsicht, ob aktuell noch ein Austausch stattfindet.